# How to decode a JWT token in waterlock

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js

I am using waterlock for authentication in a sails.js app and want to add a custom attribute to jwt.
I am not able to find in the doc, how I can decode and access the jwt token in policies. I don't want to add any third party decoding libraries as I am already using waterlock.
So far I've done this by req.session.user.group.id but ideally I would want to access the group id directly through jwt.

Answer (score 0):

Waterlocks installs jwt-simple module so I guess you should be able to use  [jwt.decode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-simple)